# Trying to understand flock structure parameter in fcntl()

Tags: locking

I am trying to understand fcntl system call , which has this structure as the second parameter:

```
struct flock fl;
int fd;

fl.l_type   = F_WRLCK;  /* F_RDLCK, F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK    */
fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET; /* SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END */
fl.l_start  = 0;        /* Offset from l_whence         */
fl.l_len    = 0;        /* length, 0 = to EOF           */
fl.l_pid    = getpid(); /* our PID
```

I want to know what exactly is `fl.l_start`

so for example if I  make it `fl.l_start = 5`, does that mean that protection is guaranteed only beyond 5 bytes from the beginning?

(i.e before 5 bytes, no lock is there so, all the processes can have access to it in a non-cooperative manner.)